# How to get the response of cmd from using os.system?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am changing folder and running a program. The code works but I would like to capture the response from the command line to be sure the execution of the program was successful.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('C:/Program Files/ABX/App/')
print(os.getcwd())
command = 'abx.exe'
response = os.system(command)
```

Response gives me an integer of 1. How can I catch the response of command line after executing `os.system(command)`

Comment: Consider using `subprocess.check_output`! https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Thanks. I used subprocess lib instead. Those who need to change path to a default, use cwd='Path'